# How to embed youtube in custom field buddy press

Tags: youtube, buddypress

How do you embed YouTube in a custom field for the user's profile in Buddy Press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below link, hope this will help you,

http://snippetbarn.bp-fr.net/how-to-embed-a-video-on-profile/

```
function set_video_field( $field_value ) {
    $bp_this_field_name = bp_get_the_profile_field_name();
    // field name (case sensitive)
    if( $bp_this_field_name == 'Spotlight' ) {
        $field_value = strip_tags( $field_value );
        // building the HTML and h/w of the iframe
        $field_value = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$field_value.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
    return $field_value;
}
add_filter( 'bp_get_the_profile_field_value','set_video_field');
```